# Ошибка открытия второго MainApp при помощи нажатии кнопки в первом MainApp

Tags: javafx

Помогите пожалуйста для моего случая написать метод запуска открытия джифрейма `MainApp.java` нажатии кнопки "ОK" в джифрейме `UchetUspevaemosti.java` 
Коды программ :

1) UchetUspevemosti.java:

```
package ch.makery.address;

import java.io.IOException;
import ch.makery.address.MainApp;
import ch.makery.address.PrepodMainApp;
import ch.makery.address.StudentMainApp;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
public class UchetUspevaemosti extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Scene scene;
    Button buttonOk;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Uchet Uspevaemosti Studentov");
        buttonOk = new Button("OK");

        ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();

        //getItems return the Observablelist object wich you can add items to
        //choiceBox.getItems().add("Methodist");
        choiceBox.getItems().addAll("Methodist","Prepod","Student");

        //setItems
        choiceBox.setValue("Methodist");

        buttonOk.setOnAction(e-> getChoice(choiceBox));

        VBox layout =new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets (100,125,73,125));

        layout.getChildren().addAll(choiceBox,buttonOk);

        scene = new Scene(layout, 350,250);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    private Object getChoice(ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox) {
        String person = choiceBox.getValue();
        if (person == "Methodist"){
            //zapuskaetsya Metodist;
         MainApp Metodist = new MainApp();
         Metodist.main(new String[] {});
         Metodist.showOcenkiOverview();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

2)MainApp.java:

```
package ch.makery.address;

import java.io.IOException;
import ch.makery.address.model.Ocenki;
import ch.makery.address.model.GhurnalOcenok;
import ch.makery.address.view.BarChartStatisticController;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

     private Stage primaryStage;
        private BorderPane rootLayout;

        //коллекция
        private static ObservableList<Ocenki> ocenkiData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        private static ObservableList<GhurnalOcenok> ghurnalocenokData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public static ObservableList<GhurnalOcenok> getGhurnalOcenokList() {
            return ghurnalocenokData;

        }
        public static ObservableList<Ocenki> getOcenkiList() {
            return ocenkiData;

        }

        public MainApp() {
            // Add some sample data
            //table
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            this.primaryStage.setTitle("TCPP");

            initRootLayout();
            showOcenkiOverview();

        }

        /**
         * Initializes the root layout.
         */
        public void initRootLayout() {
            try {
                // Load root layout from fxml file.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayoutMetodist.fxml"));//  view/PrepodRootLayout.fxml
                rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

                // Show the scene containing the root layout.
                Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        /**
         * Shows the person overview inside the root layout.
         */
        public void showOcenkiOverview() {
            try {
                // Load person overview.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/MetodistOverview.fxml"));// view/PrepodOverviewController.fxml
                AnchorPane metodistOverview = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

                // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
                rootLayout.setCenter(metodistOverview);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns the main stage.
         * @return
         */
        public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
            return primaryStage;
        }




        /**
         * Opens a dialog to show Razmer statistics.
         */
        public void showBarChartStatistic() {
           try {
                // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/BarChartStatistic.fxml"));//
                AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

                Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
                dialogStage.setTitle("Razmer(diagonal) Statistics");
                dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
                Scene scene = new Scene(page);
                dialogStage.setScene(scene);

                // Set the persons into the controller.
                BarChartStatisticController controller = loader.getController();

                controller.setOcenkiData( ocenkiData);

                dialogStage.show();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();   
            }
        }

           /**
         * Opens a dialog to show  Current Ocenki for all school year.
         */

    public void showCurrentOcenkiStudent() {
         try {
                // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/Current Ocenki Studenta.fxml"));//
                AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

                Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
                dialogStage.setTitle("Current Ocenki for all learning year");
                dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
                Scene scene = new Scene(page);
                dialogStage.setScene(scene);

                // Set the persons into the controller.
                //BarChartStatisticController controller = loader.getController();

                //controller.setOcenkiData( ghurnalocenokData);

                dialogStage.show();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();   
            }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```